# How can I login to instagram using php and curl and get a sessionid?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, instagram, session-cookies

I am using this PHP code found in the answer on this question :
[Instagram login programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003063/instagram-login-programmatically)
When I check the cookie.txt sessionid is "" . is there a way I can change this code to make it get a sessionid cookie ? csrftoken,rur,mid,urlgen all seem to be set correctly but I dont know...I need the sessionid to explore tags programmatically.

EDIT: The problem is for my username and password I am being directed to the "Suspicious Login Attempt" page.
"We Detected An Unusual Login Attempt
To secure your account, let us know if it was you"
EDIT : one of my account works every time ,only the other shows the "Suspicious Login Attempt" page. ??? :/  ???

what is that all about ?

```
$username = "yourname";
$password = "yourpass";
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/50.0.2661.102 Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36";
$cookie=$username.".txt";

@unlink(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);

$url="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login";

$ch  = curl_init();        

$arrSetHeaders = array(
    "User-Agent: $useragent",
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding: deflate, br',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'cache-control: max-age=0',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrSetHeaders);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);          

// try to find the actual login form
if (!preg_match('/<form method="POST" id="login-form" class="adjacent".*?<\/form>/is', $page, $form)) {
    die('Failed to find log in form!');
}

$form = $form[0];

// find the action of the login form
if (!preg_match('/action="([^"]+)"/i', $form, $action)) {
    die('Failed to find login form url');
}

$url2 = $action[1]; // this is our new post url
// find all hidden fields which we need to send with our login, this includes security tokens
$count = preg_match_all('/<input type="hidden"\s*name="([^"]*)"\s*value="([^"]*)"/i', $form, $hiddenFields);

$postFields = array();

// turn the hidden fields into an array
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $postFields[$hiddenFields[1][$i]] = $hiddenFields[2][$i];
}

// add our login values
$postFields['username'] = $username;
$postFields['password'] = $password;   

$post = '';

// convert to string, this won't work as an array, form will not accept multipart/form-data, only application/x-www-form-urlencoded
foreach($postFields as $key => $value) {
    $post .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
}

$post = substr($post, 0, -1);   

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $page, $matches);

$cookieFileContent = '';

foreach($matches[1] as $item) 
{
    $cookieFileContent .= "$item; ";
}

$cookieFileContent = rtrim($cookieFileContent, '; ');
$cookieFileContent = str_replace('sessionid=; ', '', $cookieFileContent);

$oldContent = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
$oldContArr = explode("\n", $oldContent);

if(count($oldContArr))
{
    foreach($oldContArr as $k => $line)
    {
        if(strstr($line, '# '))
        {
            unset($oldContArr[$k]);
        }
    }

    $newContent = implode("\n", $oldContArr);
    $newContent = trim($newContent, "\n");

    file_put_contents(
        dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie,
        $newContent
    );    
}

$arrSetHeaders = array(
    'origin: https://www.instagram.com',
    'authority: www.instagram.com',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
    'Host: www.instagram.com',
    "User-Agent: $useragent",
    'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding: deflate, br',
    "Referer: $url",
    "Cookie: $cookieFileContent",
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'cache-control: max-age=0',
);

$ch  = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrSetHeaders);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);        

sleep(5);
$page = curl_exec($ch);


preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $page, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie1);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie1);
}
var_dump($page);      

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: [don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1067003), PHP has perfectly good HTML parsers, like DOMDocument.

Comment: I assume this script doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
$cookieFileContent = str_replace('sessionid=; ', '', $cookieFileContent);
```

for

```
$cookieFileContent = str_replace('sessionid=""; ', '', $cookieFileContent);
```

Add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

And you will be logged in.

It works:

```
define('USERNAME', "");
define('PASSWORD', "");
define('USERAGENT', "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36");
define('COOKIE', USERNAME.".txt");

function login_inst() {

    @unlink(dirname(__FILE__)."/!instagram/".COOKIE);

    $url="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login";

    $ch  = curl_init(); 

    $arrSetHeaders = array(
        "User-Agent: USERAGENT",
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding: deflate, br',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'cache-control: max-age=0',
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrSetHeaders);         
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__)."/!instagram/".COOKIE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__)."/!instagram/".COOKIE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USERAGENT);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);  

    //var_dump($page);

    // try to find the actual login form
    if (!preg_match('/<form method="POST" id="login-form" class="adjacent".*?<\/form>/is', $page, $form)) {
        die('Failed to find log in form!');
    }

    $form = $form[0];

    // find the action of the login form
    if (!preg_match('/action="([^"]+)"/i', $form, $action)) {
        die('Failed to find login form url');
    }

    $url2 = $action[1]; // this is our new post url
    // find all hidden fields which we need to send with our login, this includes security tokens
    $count = preg_match_all('/<input type="hidden"\s*name="([^"]*)"\s*value="([^"]*)"/i', $form, $hiddenFields);

    $postFields = array();

    // turn the hidden fields into an array
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
        $postFields[$hiddenFields[1][$i]] = $hiddenFields[2][$i];
    }

    // add our login values
    $postFields['username'] = USERNAME;
    $postFields['password'] = PASSWORD;   

    $post = '';

    // convert to string, this won't work as an array, form will not accept multipart/form-data, only application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    foreach($postFields as $key => $value) {
        $post .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
    }

    $post = substr($post, 0, -1);   

    preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $page, $matches);

    $cookieFileContent = '';

    foreach($matches[1] as $item) 
    {
        $cookieFileContent .= "$item; ";
    }

    $cookieFileContent = rtrim($cookieFileContent, '; ');
    $cookieFileContent = str_replace('sessionid=""; ', '', $cookieFileContent);

    $oldContent = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/!instagram/".COOKIE);
    $oldContArr = explode("\n", $oldContent);

    if(count($oldContArr))
    {
        foreach($oldContArr as $k => $line)
        {
            if(strstr($line, '# '))
            {
                unset($oldContArr[$k]);
            }
        }

        $newContent = implode("\n", $oldContArr);
        $newContent = trim($newContent, "\n");

        file_put_contents(
            dirname(__FILE__)."/!instagram/".COOKIE,
            $newContent
        );    
    }

    $arrSetHeaders = array(
        'origin: https://www.instagram.com',
        'authority: www.instagram.com',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
        'Host: www.instagram.com',
        "User-Agent: USERAGENT",
        'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding: deflate, br',
        "Referer: $url",
        "Cookie: $cookieFileContent",
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'cache-control: max-age=0',
    );

    $ch  = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__)."/!instagram/".COOKIE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__)."/!instagram/".COOKIE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USERAGENT);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrSetHeaders);     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    sleep(5);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);

    /*
    preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $page, $matches);
    COOKIEs = array();
    foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
        parse_str($item, COOKIE1);
        COOKIEs = array_merge(COOKIEs, COOKIE1);
    }
    */
    //var_dump($page);      
    curl_close($ch);  

}
```

This function return Instagram page by url:

```
function curl_inst($url) { 

    $arrSetHeaders = array(
        'origin: https://www.instagram.com',
        'authority: www.instagram.com',
        'method: GET',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
        'Host: www.instagram.com',
        "User-Agent: USERAGENT",
        'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'accept-language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6',
        'accept-encoding: deflate, br',
        "Referer: https://www.instagram.com",
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'cache-control: max-age=0',
    );
    $ch  = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__)."/!instagram/".COOKIE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__)."/!instagram/".COOKIE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); //connection timeout in seconds 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USERAGENT);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrSetHeaders);     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $page = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
      switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
        case 200:  # OK
          //echo 'All OK: ', $http_code, "\n";
          //var_dump($page);    
          curl_close($ch);
          return $page;    
        default:
          echo 'Error: ', $http_code, "\n";
          curl_close($ch);    
          break;    
      }
    }      

}
```

Next step:

```
login_inst();
sleep(5);
$page = curl_inst('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/stackoverflow/');
var_dump($page);
```

Comment: _EDIT : one of my account works every time ,only the other shows the "Suspicious Login Attempt" page. ??? :/ ???_  try not to login at instagram for a few days

Comment: Very good one. There's a small change nowadays `<form data-encrypt method="POST"` - the _data-encrypt_ was added.

Comment: Using this code I get `HTTP/2 400 Bad request`

Comment: Instagram browser app sends password in an encoded form now.

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: The problem is for my username and password I am being directed to the "Suspicious Login Attempt" page. "We Detected An Unusual Login Attempt To secure your account, let us know if it was you"

Facebook/Instagram is (correctly) detecting you're trying to violate their Terms of Service, which forbid this sort of thing, and has thus put a roadblock in place that probably requires you to do something like solve a CAPTCHA.

You should use [the official Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) instead.

Comment: This official API is almost useless since you'll need approval, making it annoying for individual developers to experiment new ideas.

Comment: @ttvd94 Developers bypass approval requirements. Approval is only needed to make the app available to others. Experiment away!