# Misspelled RegEx in PHP function preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, curl, instagram

This is a question about PHP, [cURL](http://php.net/curl), [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), RegEx, and Instagram.

I'm trying to write a cURL PHP code that logs-in to Instagram, and then access content only available to a validated (logged-in) user. [In this question there's an interesting code just for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37711728/3958567).

I copy-pasted the code, which is the following:

```
<?php
$username = "yourname";
$password = "yourpass";
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/50.0.2661.102 Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36";
$cookie=$username.".txt";

@unlink(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);

$url="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login";

$ch  = curl_init();        

$arrSetHeaders = array(
    "User-Agent: $useragent",
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding: deflate, br',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'cache-control: max-age=0',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrSetHeaders);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);          

// try to find the actual login form
if (!preg_match('/<form method="POST" id="login-form" class="adjacent".*?<\/form>/is', $page, $form)) {
    die('Failed to find log in form!');
}

$form = $form[0];

// find the action of the login form
if (!preg_match('/action="([^"]+)"/i', $form, $action)) {
    die('Failed to find login form url');
}

$url2 = $action[1]; // this is our new post url
// find all hidden fields which we need to send with our login, this includes security tokens
$count = preg_match_all('/<input type="hidden"\s*name="([^"]*)"\s*value="([^"]*)"/i', $form, $hiddenFields);

$postFields = array();

// turn the hidden fields into an array
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $postFields[$hiddenFields[1][$i]] = $hiddenFields[2][$i];
}

// add our login values
$postFields['username'] = $username;
$postFields['password'] = $password;   

$post = '';

// convert to string, this won't work as an array, form will not accept multipart/form-data, only application/x-www-form-urlencoded
foreach($postFields as $key => $value) {
    $post .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
}

$post = substr($post, 0, -1);   

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $page, $matches);

$cookieFileContent = '';

foreach($matches[1] as $item) 
{
    $cookieFileContent .= "$item; ";
}

$cookieFileContent = rtrim($cookieFileContent, '; ');
$cookieFileContent = str_replace('sessionid=; ', '', $cookieFileContent);

$oldContent = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
$oldContArr = explode("\n", $oldContent);

if(count($oldContArr))
{
    foreach($oldContArr as $k => $line)
    {
        if(strstr($line, '# '))
        {
            unset($oldContArr[$k]);
        }
    }

    $newContent = implode("\n", $oldContArr);
    $newContent = trim($newContent, "\n");

    file_put_contents(
        dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie,
        $newContent
    );    
}

$arrSetHeaders = array(
    'origin: https://www.instagram.com',
    'authority: www.instagram.com',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
    'Host: www.instagram.com',
    "User-Agent: $useragent",
    'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding: deflate, br',
    "Referer: $url",
    "Cookie: $cookieFileContent",
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'cache-control: max-age=0',
);

$ch  = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrSetHeaders);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);        

sleep(5);
$page = curl_exec($ch);


preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $page, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie1);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie1);
}
var_dump($page);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

You must, of course, change the `$username`'s value from `yourname` to an actual username, and `$password`'s value from `yourpass` to the corresponding password of the username. Also, I don't think this code will work if 2-step authentication is enabled in the account of the user (ie., for example, a MMS is sent to the linked phone number, or an email is sent to the linked email), therefore, 2-step authentication must be disabled in the user's account settings.

However, when I run this PHP script in Chrome, I get the message *Failed to find log in form!*, meaning that, on line 35, the pattern (written as a RegEx) `/<form method="POST" id="login-form" class="adjacent".*?<\/form>/is` wasn't found in the variable `$page`, which at the same time is basically the HTML of the [classic Instagram login page](https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login).

[image: RegEx error in preg_match() for the pattern]

It's weird that such pattern is not being found, because there's indeed a HTML named `<form method="POST" id="login-form" class="adjacent"` (to check it yourself, go to the [login page](https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login), press Ctrl+U, then Ctrl+F, and then paste the previous pattern). So, I assume this is because the RegEx is somehow misspelled. Is that correct?

Even weirder, [I tested it on the page RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sQMZ10/2), and the test was successful. So, why is PHP saying the pattern wasn't found?

[image: RegEx successful test on RegEx101.com]

The idea is that the pattern can be found in the code of the original question, so that I can log-in automatically/programmatically. Keep in mind that more `preg_match()` functions are used later in the code, eg. on lines 42, 48 (`preg_match_all()`), 70 (`preg_match_all()`), and 137 (`preg_match_all()`).

---

EDIT: I realized that if I add `var_dump($page);` just before line 35, I get `bool(false)` (in other words, the HTML output is `bool(false) Failed to find log in form!`). **I think this is the reason why the code returns the message *Failed to find log in form!***. However, why is the value of `$page` returning that?

Comment: Maybe try `echo $page` and verify that it contains the content you expect, before matching with regex.